# Check JS function when its stored in a variable with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently store a function in a variable, and then call it:

```
var function_name = 'test_function';


// some other JS here    


if (typeof app[function_name] != 'undefined') {
     app[function_name];
}


app.test_function = function() {
    alert('woo');
};
```

This works fine, but what if I store arguments in the function name variable? Like this:

```
var function_name = 'test_function("mike")';


// some other JS here    


if (typeof app[function_name] != 'undefined') {
     app[function_name];
}


app.test_function = function(name) {
    alert(name);
};
```

This doesn't work, because `typeof app[function_name]` is undefined.
How can I do this?

Comment: whats the use of statement `app[function_name];`?

Comment: what does you `app` has?

Comment: Why not pack the arguments separately from the function definition? You could then use the same logic to lookup the function and delegate _calling_ the function with the supplied arguments, much like `lodash.curry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'test_function("mike")'` is not a valid function name.

Your logic needs to change to

```js
var function_name = 'test_function("mike")';
var app = {};
app.test_function = function(name) 
{
  console.log(name)
};
var split = function_name.split(/[()]/);
var funName = split[0];
var arguments = [];
if (funName != function_name) 
{
  var arguments = split[1].split(",");
}
if (typeof app[funName] != 'undefined') 
{
  app[funName].apply(null, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`function` name should/will not change but the `definition` will!

```js
var function_name = 'test_function';
var app = {};
if (typeof app[function_name] != 'undefined') {
  app[function_name];
}
app.test_function = function(name) {
  alert(name);
};
app.test_function('Hey');
```